# Tailwind Modal Animation Z Axis Conflicting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, tailwind-css, z-index

I have a basic layout that maps elements into a Masonry Grid using the React Masonry CSS package. I have the modal animation nearly perfect, but the issue is at the start of the animation, the backdrop-blur and z-index seem to be conflicting with the other elements on the page. The opacity animates fine, but at the end of the animation the z-axis moves up to the correct spot (in front of everything else) whereas before it is behind the other elements.

It might be worth noting that I have a navigation bar at the top which also suffers the same problem. This is all coded in typescript.

Feed.tsx

```
import { storyblokEditable, StoryblokComponent } from "@storyblok/react";
import Masonry from "react-masonry-css";
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
import Navigation from "../Navigation";

export interface FeedProps {
    blok: any;
}

const Feed: FC<FeedProps> = ({ blok }) => {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    const [modalData, setModalData] = useState();

    const breakpointColumnsObj = {
        default: 4,
        1620: 3,
        1200: 2,
        700: 1,
    };

    const ModalContent = () => {
        return (
            <div className="">
                <div
                    className={`flex backdrop-blur-[1px] z-50 justify-center items-center inset-0 fixed`}
                >
                    <div className="flex flex-col p-3 border border-white/30 rounded-lg backdrop-blur bg-white/80 w-1/2">
                        {modalData?.image.id != null ? (
                            <img
                                src={modalData.image.filename}
                                alt=""
                                className="rounded-lg mb-2"
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <></>
                        )}
                        <h2
                            className={`text-black
                                    ${
                                        modalData?.description === "" && modalData.image.id === null
                                            ? "font-Eros text-2xl"
                                            : "font-bold text-md"
                                    }`}
                        >
                            {modalData?.title}
                        </h2>
                        <h2 className="text-black/60 font-light text-xs">
                            {modalData?.description}
                        </h2>
                        <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
                            <h2 className="text-black/60 font-light text-xs pt-2">
                                {modalData?.user}
                            </h2>
                            <h2 className="text-black/60 font-light text-xs pt-2">
                                {modalData?.date}
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <button
                            onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
                            className="text-white bg-lift-red self-start px-4 py-2 mt-4 rounded-lg"
                        >
                            Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* This is the background */}
                <div className={`inset-0 fixed bg-black/25`}></div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className={`w-full`} {...storyblokEditable(blok)}>
            <div
                className={`transition-all duration-300 ${
                    showModal ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
                }`}
            >
                <ModalContent />
            </div>
            <Masonry
                breakpointCols={breakpointColumnsObj}
                className="flex flex-row gap-x-3"
                columnClassName="flex flex-col space-y-3"
            >
                {blok.feed.map((nestedBlok: any) => (
                    <button
                        className={``}
                        onClick={() => {
                            setShowModal(!showModal);
                            setModalData(nestedBlok);
                        }}
                    >
                        <StoryblokComponent blok={nestedBlok} key={nestedBlok._uid} />
                    </button>
                ))}
            </Masonry>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Feed;
```